# Smoke Domain object is black

Tags: cycles-render-engine, 3d-view, smoke-simulation

So I'm really new to blender and I'm trying to get a book to catch on fire and fall over, but for some reason the domain for the smoke system is totally black. Not sure what to do or what I did. Any idea what's happening?

[image]

[image]

That's how it looks before I hit play

Comment: Possibly a hardware/driver problem?

Comment: I wouldn't know. Right after I hit Smoke and change it to domain in the Physics tab it becomes black...

Comment: could you upload your .blend?

Comment: Have you given it a material?

Comment: @PGmath I don't think a material would make any difference in solid view..

Comment: @gandalf3 Ah, I didn't notice it was in solid view mode.  Pretty dimwitted of me!

Comment: Are you on CPU or GPU mode? GPU mode causes this as volumetrics are not supported on GPU yet.

Answer (score 3):

To see if it's a hardware problem, you can always create a 'Quick Effect'. If that doesn't work, then your PC hardware is having trouble rendering the smoke (but that's unlikely). If it does work, then you now have a working setup as a reference.

1. To create a Quick Smoke, start with a new Blender file, then select
   the default cube.
2. Call up the search box with <kbd>Spacebar</kbd>and type in 'Quick Smoke'.
3. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to see the effect.

[image: Quick effects search]

Comment: Why are people giving this a thumbs up?  What evidence do you have?  This happens on my computer, also: the "quick smoke" option renders absolutely nothing.  It only becomes a black box after fiddling around with the settings until "flow" or "effector" is selected.  Domain just shows an empty box.  Screwed around with this for hours.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem. This Video helped me: https://youtu.be/xH0O4bMalhg?t=3m19s

The problem is that the default material of the smoke/fire domain is a Blender material, not a Cycles material. To change it to a Cycles material you have to do this:

1. In the material settings of the domain cube click on "Use nodes"
2. Change the material like in this image:
   [image]

Answer (score -2):

Solution.

AMD video cards do not support fire or smoke rendering, you will get the domain box rendered instead.

You will have to render using CPU only.

Comment: Welcome to the site. This is not a solution because as seen from OP's screenshot black box appeared in Solid shading, not in Rendered, so no rendering happened yet.